# Why is skimage.euler_number gives me euler number of 1, but according to the formula it should give me 2

Tags: python, image-processing, shapes

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import euler_number
n = 7
cube = np.zeros((n, n, n), dtype=int)
cube[1:6,1:6,1:6] = 1 #creates a cube of 5x5
euler_no = euler_number(cube)
```

'This is giving me o/p as 1 but according to the formula euler_number = F + V − E it should give me 2 as number of faces = 6, number of vertices = 8 and number of edges = 12 but using this method I am getting Euler number as 1. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like skimage does this wrong. The [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.euler_number) states:

> For 3D objects, the Euler number is obtained as the number of objects plus the number of holes, minus the number of tunnels, or loops.

According to their definition, a cube (or any solid object) has an Euler number of 1. Unfortunately their definition is wrong. In particular, I believe it always returns half the Euler number in 3D. If I’m right, to get the actual 3D Euler number,

```
euler_no = 2 * euler_number(cube)
```

Comment: I am using this method to find Euler Number of an irregular shaped objects. are there any other packages which can give me right Euler Number of irregular objects?

Comment: @VivekSthanam: check the edit to my answer.

Comment: but I don't know if it holds true to irregular objects like a snake or worm

Comment: @VivekSthanam: any solid object without holes or loops has an Euler characteristic of 2.